# How can I tell if the screen is navigated to with ReactNavigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'd like to refresh the data on the screen in a react native app whenever the screen appears - like in a `ViewWillAppear` method.  I tried using the `componentWillMount` method but it looks like it fires once before it appears, and doesn't fire again when the view is navigated to again.

Looking at this example https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/screen-tracking, it looks like I can add a listener on the `onNavigationStateChange` method on the root navigation, but I'd like to keep the logic in the screen as it gets confusing if I move the data fetch logic for that one scree outside to the root navigator.

I've tried to follow the example and set that method to my stacknavigation but it doesn't seem to trigger.

```
  <RootNavigation ref={nav => { this.navigator = nav; }}
    onNavigationStateChange={(prevState, currentState, action) => {

      // maybe here I can fire redux event or something to let screens
      // know that they are getting focus - however it doesn't fire so
      // I might be implementing this incorrectly

      const currentScreen = getCurrentRouteName(currentState);
      const prevScreen = getCurrentRouteName(prevState);

      if (prevScreen !== currentScreen) {
        console.log('navigating to this screen', currentScreen);
      }
    }}
  />
```

Comment: Are you using Redux or how are you managing app state? I think you would set currentRouteName with the react navigation example you posted. Then connect the screen to monitor currentRouteName. `componentWillReceiveProps` is where you would put the code to monitor if current screen is active/changing... if using redux that is.

Comment: I'm using redux - but react-navigtaion does it's own thing with redux and has its own actions and reducers - which I'm trying to figure out how it hooks into.  Right now it's a black box for me

Comment: I just set this up and confirmed to have it working based on the Screen tracking with redux example. Can you post your reducer and I'll give you a specific example. You don't need to use all of the first example, specifically you don't need an onNavigationStateChange function.

Comment: I don't actually have a navigation reducer - do you mean integrating with redux like in their docs?  I've continued the comment in your answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So here's how I did it using the `onNavigateStateChange`.

```
      <RootNavigation
        ref={nav => { this.navigator = nav; }}
        uriPrefix={prefix}
        onNavigationStateChange={(prevState, currentState) => {
          const currentScreen = this.getCurrentRouteName(currentState);
          const prevScreen = this.getCurrentRouteName(prevState);
          if (prevScreen !== currentScreen) {
            this.props.emitActiveScreen(currentScreen);
            {/*console.log('onNavigationStateChange', currentScreen);*/}
          }
        }}
      />
```

And in your screen you can check to see if your view will appear, note `MyPage` is the route name from your navigation object.

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if ((nextProps.activeScreen === 'MyPage' && nextProps.activeScreen !== this.props.activeScreen)) {
      // do your on view will appear logic here
    }
  }
```

Comment: what does `emitActiveScreen` stands for? I search `emitActiveScreen` in https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=emitActiveScreen&type=, but got nothing here

Comment: @Halt I use `DeviceEventEmitter` in `react-native` instead

Answer (score 2):

Here is my navigator reducer.

```
function getCurrentRouteName(navState) {
  if (!navState) {
    return null;
  }

  const navigationState = (navState && navState.toJS && navState.toJS()) || navState;

  const route = navigationState.routes[navigationState.index];
  // dive into nested navigators
  if (route.routes) {
    return getCurrentRouteName(route);
  }

  return route.routeName;
}


export default function NavigatorReducer(state, action) {
  // Initial state
  if (!state) {
    return fromJS(AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state));
  }

  // Is this a navigation action that we should act upon?
  if (includes(NavigationActions, action.type)) {
    // lets find currentScreen before this action based on state
    const currentScreen = getCurrentRouteName(state);
    const nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state.toJS());
    // determine what the new screen will be after this action was performed
    const nextScreen = getCurrentRouteName(nextState);

    if (nextScreen !== currentScreen) {
      nextState.currentRoute = nextScreen;
      console.log(`screen changed, punk: ${currentScreen} -> ${nextScreen}`);
    }

    return fromJS(nextState);
  }

  return state;
}
```

And then we have to connect the module/route to the redux store (sceneIsActive is the important bit):

```
export default connect(
  state => ({
    counter: state.getIn(['counter', 'value']),
    loading: state.getIn(['counter', 'loading']),
    sceneIsActive: state.getIn(['navigatorState', 'currentRoute']) === 'Counter',
  }),
  dispatch => {
    return {
      navigate: bindActionCreators(NavigationActions.navigate, dispatch),
      counterStateActions: bindActionCreators(CounterStateActions, dispatch),
    };
  },
)(CounterView);
```

And then inside your component, you can watch for/trigger code when the scene becomes active:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.sceneIsActive && (this.props.sceneIsActive !== nextProps.sceneIsActive)) {
      console.log('counter view is now active, do something about it', this.props.sceneIsActive, nextProps.sceneIsActive);
      doSomethingWhenScreenBecomesActive();
    }
  }
```

Know that `componentWillReceiveProps` does not run when initially mounted. So don't forget to call your `doSomethingWhenScreenBecomesActive` there as well.

Comment: Would this require integrating with redux like so?  https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/redux.  If so it sounds like there is more plumbing todo since the docs warn: `you are now responsible for persisting its state, handling any deep linking, integrating the back button, etc.`

Comment: I ended up using onNavigationStateChange to trigger the nav events into my own redux - rather than re-implmenting react-navigation state, or doing the more thorough redux integration in their docs.  Using your `componentWillRecieveProps` approach from there on out works fine.  The reason `componentWillRecieveProps` wasn't working was because I wasn't on the latest react-navigation version.  Once I updated that it worked.

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey I also wanted to avoid passing in navigation prop due to that docs warning. Can you share a gist of how you are able to use onNavigationStateChange to keep to keep the screen tracking gin the redux store? I am not using Immutable JS

Answer (score 1):

You can use focus/blur event listeners(demonstrated [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/pull/3345/files#diff-a67bfc346bec625c878caa96e4c63a4f) and discussed [here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/51)).