# How to re-render a tab in React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a React-Native flashcard app that boots with two tabs, a Home tab, and a New Deck tab. The Home tab is the default, and you can press or swipe over to the New Deck tab.

- The Home tab displays all of the decks the user currently has saved.
- On the New Deck tab, I have the user enter the title of their new deck and press a submit button. When that submit button is pressed, I re-navigate to the Home tab.

**My issue is**: How in the world do I trigger a re-render on the Home tab from a button press on the New Deck tab so the user can see the deck they just created?

I know I could use Redux to solve this issue, but no other part of the app is optimized in a "Redux" fashion, and I'd really like to not redesign the architecture of my app for the sole purpose of updating a single screen, mostly because this is the only instance where I would need this ability.

I've attempted to get around this by passing screenProps containing the this.forceUpdate method all the way from the StackNavigator component, but it didn't work. I also tried manually update the state of the App component to trigger a re-render, but the re-render never happened (although the state did update).

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'
import AlphaHome from './Components/Home/AlphaHome'
import AlphaQuiz from './Components/Quiz/AlphaQuiz'
import AlphaNewUdaciDeck from './Components/NewUdaciDeck/AlphaNewUdaciDeck'
import AlphaNewUdaciCard from './Components/NewUdaciCard/AlphaNewUdaciCard'
import AlphaUdaciDeckDetails from './Components/UdaciDeckDetails/AlphaUdaciDeckDetails'
import { TabNavigator, StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'

const Tabs = TabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: AlphaHome,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Home',
    },
  },
  NewDeck: {
    screen: AlphaNewUdaciDeck,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'New Deck',
    }
  }
}, {
  navigationOptions: {
    header: null,
  },
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: 'white',
    indicatorStyle: {
      backgroundColor: 'white'
    },
    style: {
      height: 50,
      borderBottomColor: 'white',
      backgroundColor: 'deepskyblue',
    }
  },
})

const Stack = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Tabs,
  },
  AlphaNewUdaciDeck: {
    screen: AlphaNewUdaciDeck,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTintColor: 'white',
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'deepskyblue'
      }
    }
  },
  AlphaNewUdaciCard: {
    screen: AlphaNewUdaciCard,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTintColor: 'white',
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'deepskyblue'
      }
    }
  },
  AlphaUdaciDeckDetails: {
    screen: AlphaUdaciDeckDetails,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTintColor: 'white',
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'deepskyblue'
      }
    }
  },
})

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Stack />
    )
  }
}
```

**Home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { ScrollView, View, Text, StyleSheet, AsyncStorage, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native'
import UdaciDeck from '../Reusable/UdaciDeck'
import { getAllData } from '../../utils/AsyncApi'

export default class HomeExistingUser extends Component {
  state = {
    decks: null,
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    let decks = getAllData()
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        decks
      })
    }, 1000)
  }
  showDetails = (title, count) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('AlphaUdaciDeckDetails', {title, count})
  }
  render() {
    const {decks} = this.state
    return (
      decks
      ? <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
            {decks.map(s => <UdaciDeck key={s[1].title} name={s[1].title} count={s[1].questions.length} method={this.showDetails} />)}
        </ScrollView>
      : <View style={[styles.container, {flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center'}]}>
          <ActivityIndicator size='large' color='white' />
        </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    minHeight: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'lightskyblue',
    paddingTop: 20,
    paddingBottom: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
})
```

**NewDeck.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text, TextInput, StyleSheet, AsyncStorage, TouchableNativeFeedback, Alert } from 'react-native'
import { addDeck } from '../../utils/AsyncApi'

// BUG: when adding a new deck (if HomeExistingUser is true) view doesn't update. Need to figure out a way to update on tab navigate back

export default class AlphaNewUdaciDeck extends Component {
  state = {
    input: '',
    keys: null,
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getAllKeys()
      .then(keys => this.setState({
        keys
      }))
  }
  handleSubmit = () => {
    const {input, keys} = this.state
    input.search(' ') > 0 || input.length < 1 || keys.filter(s => s === input).length > 0
      ? Alert.alert(`Please enter a valid name (${input.length < 1 || keys.filter(s => s === input).length > 0 ? `you can't save a deck with ${input.length < 1 ? 'no' : 'an already used'} name` : "no spaces"})`)
      : addDeck(input)
    ;if(input.search(' ') < 0 || input.length > 0 || keys.filter(s => s === input).length < 1) {
      this.props.navigation.goBack()
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container, styles.containerOne]}>
         <View style={styles.containerTwo}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>Name of the deck</Text>
            <Text style={styles.text}>(Please no spaces)</Text>
            <TextInput
              autoFocus={true}
              onChangeText={(input) => this.setState({
                input
              })}
              selectionColor={'deepskyblue'}
              underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
              style={styles.input}
            />
            <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={this.handleSubmit}>
              <View style={styles.btn}>
                <Text style={styles.btnText}>Save Deck</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableNativeFeedback>
          </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'lightskyblue',
  },
  containerOne: {
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  containerTwo: {
    marginTop: 50,
  },
  text: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  input: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    height: 50,
    width: 300,
    marginTop: 15,
    fontSize: 20,
    paddingLeft: 5,
    paddingRight: 5,
    color: 'deepskyblue'
  },
  btn: {
    backgroundColor: 'deepskyblue',
    marginTop: 50,
    padding: 20,
    paddingLeft: 50,
    paddingRight: 50,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  btnText: {
    color: 'white',
  },
})
```

Comment: If you are using Redux, you don't need to do anything special other then updating the global store for the tabs to update. If the tabs aren't updating, you may be mutating your state causing the updates to not be seen by react. I also did the udacity course and have a finished project at https://github.com/steveone/mobile-flashcards if you want to check it out. I used stackNavigator instead of tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out react-navigation-is-focused-hoc at https://github.com/pmachowski/react-navigation-is-focused-hoc to solve the specific problem you mentioned.

You can also try

```
onNavigationStateChange(prevState, newState)
```

there is a sample at [How can I tell if the screen is navigated to with ReactNavigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770148/how-can-i-tell-if-the-screen-is-navigated-to-with-reactnavigation)

Comment: Great to see another who's gone through the struggle of this React course! Thanks a lot for the links, they got me out of that rut and I can finally submit the project.

Comment: Glad to help.. Good luck